# GIT: repository not found (SSH is working and repository is correctly spelled)

Tags: git, github

I have a bunch of scripts that I would like to upload into a repository I created online.

I did the following:

```
$git add

$git commit

$git remote add origin git@github.com:<USERNAME>/My-scripts.git **[i copied this from the website]**

$git push

$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I checked to make sure I have access to SSH

```
$ssh -T git@github.com

Hi <name>! you've successfully authenticated,  . . . .
```

I have several email addresses set up with my one github account and the one I am using is my primary address.

Below is my .gihub/config

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:<userrname>/My-scripts.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Any advice?

Comment: There must be colon between github.com and username

Comment: I did use a colon, I just mistyped in the post above.

Comment: Make sure origin and master both exist. Adding your git config file to the question (`.git/config`) might help us determine that.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a local branch called master.  Try `git branch -va` to see what branches are available.  Paste the results here if you want us to help you interpret them.  Also, whatever branch you are on, `git push -u origin` (with the extra `-u` and the branch implicitly set to the current branch) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've created the repo on GitHub? If you load

```
https://github.com/<username>/My-scripts.git
```

in your browser, do you see the repo there? Make sure you type `<username>/my-scripts.git` exactly as it appears in `.git/config`. If you see a 404 page, your repo doesn't exist yet, and you need to create it on GitHub first. Could be a small spelling error.

Comment: Thanks. I wish it were that simple. I copied the address from github <copy and paste icon>. I even double checked with your method above and my repo is spelled exactly as I have it in my config file.